# android.support libraries must use the exact same version specification

Tags: java, android, google-maps, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

I am working on Google Maps. When I try to add below dependencies, i get this error. `android.support libraries must use the exact same version specification (mixing versions can lead to runtime crashes). Found versions 23.2.1, 23.0.0. Examples include`com.android.support:animated-vector-drawable:23.2.1`and`com.android.support:mediarouter-v7:23.0.0

I am getting error in this line `compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.2.1'`

Here is my gradle:

```
    apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion '25.0.0'

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "gs.app.lugmah"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 3
        versionName "1.2"
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
    }

    lintOptions {
        xmlReport false
        warningsAsErrors true
        quiet false
        showAll true
        disable 'OldTargetApi', 'UnusedAttribute', 'LongLogTag'
    }
}
dependencies {
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.2.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.2.1'
    compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.6.1'
    compile 'com.baoyz.swipemenulistview:library:1.3.0'
    compile 'com.loopj.android:android-async-http:1.4.9'
    compile 'com.github.vlonjatg:progress-activity:v1.0.3'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:9.0.0'
    compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.11.0'
    compile 'com.facebook.fresco:fresco:0.10.0'
    compile 'com.github.nicolasjafelle:paginglistview:1.2'

}
```

If i comment this line `compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.0.0'` then it works fine with no error or red line on `compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.2.1'`
Can anyone help me to solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not use play services all modules just add

```
     compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:9.0.0'
```

Comment: Thank you so much. You saved my day.